# Calculating growth rate

Tags: python, python-2.7

hi i am trying to calculate the growth rate in percentages from a list

```
def growth():

   population = [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12]

   # new list for growth rates
   growth_rate = []

   # for population in list
   for pop in population:

       gnumbers = ((population[pop] - population[pop-1]) / population[pop-1] * 100)
       growth_rate.append(gnumbers)
       print growth_rate

growth()
```

but it gives me an index error here (gnumbers) "IndexError, index is out of range"

Comment: Please post your questions as Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  They are much easier to work with.

Comment: Ok will certainly keep that in mind, but there is not much wrong with this question in my opinion?

Comment: This question isn't so bad, but your last was terrible.  You'll get better answers, and probably figure out half of the problems on your way if you post as MCVs.  Plus, if you post MCVs, the people who answer will probably run the code before they post their answers, which will be both better, and less work, for you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `pop` iterates over the *values* of `population`, not over the indices. To iterate over the indices (except zero), write:

```
for pop in range(1, len(population)):
```

Another thing to be aware of is that the following uses *integer division*:

```
gnumbers = ((population[pop] - population[pop-1]) / population[pop-1] * 100)
                                                  ^ HERE
```

What this does is truncate the result to an integer. Given your data, it seems pretty clear that you don't want that. Here is one way to rephrase the expression to avoid this problem:

```
gnumbers = ((population[pop] - population[pop-1]) * 100.0 / population[pop-1])
```

Once you multiply by `100.0` (which is a floating-point number), you get a floating-point result and the subsequent division will not truncate to an integer.

Comment: one more thing, it gives me the whole list, but in a paramide form. You know, that he prints the lists individually from the start for the first element, then the first and the second etc. How can i fix that?

Comment: @TychoAtsma: You need to move the `print` out of the loop.

Answer (score 5):

sorry, couldn't help my self:

```
import numpy as np

growth_rate = np.exp(np.diff(np.log(population))) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What NPE suggests will work, I would also suggest using enumerate when you want both the index and value of a list:

```
for pop_index,pop_val in enumerate(population):
```

Comment: `enumerate()` is great, but I don't think it's a particularly good fit for this use case.